# Software & Update settings are not saving

Tags: 20.04, updates, lubuntu, settings

I installed Ubuntu but getting weird issues where I change this setting:

[image: immediately install]

But when I click `Close` and go back into the setting, it reverts back to:

[image: not saved]

It also seems to always find updates but when I `Install Now` it shows a progress bar then disappears.

Running: UBUNTU 20.04.01 LTS Codename: Focal

Comment: Could you specify which version of Ubuntu you’ve installed? There are quite a few 

Comment: My bad > Running: UBUNTU 20.04.01 LTS Codename: Focal

Comment: You still have *lubuntu* tagged, your last comment, plus pictures do not look anything like Lubuntu or a LXQt desktop, or programs used to amend the features you're asking for (they look more like GNOME & default Ubuntu desktop).  For Lubuntu you can view the relevant part of the manual at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/Installing_Updating_and_Removing_Software.html